# how to fix this right-to-left script issue in js string?

Tags: javascript, string, text

I would like the default behavior instead of this right-to-left script issue when using the strange string.

**I cannot even type the expected output in the question. The browser automatically puts it in the wrong side.**

```js
var strange = "د.إ";
var common = "$";

var amount = 50;
var str_common = common + amount;
var str_strange = strange + amount;

alert(str_common);

// unexpected output
alert(str_strange);

// unexpected output
alert(str_common + ' -- ' + str_strange);

// unexpected output
alert(str_strange + ' -- ' + str_common);
```

js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rahulroy9202/xL7cu2os/1/

Comment: a relevant xkcd

http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1137:_RTL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of the unicode control character `U+202A` to force it LTR:

```
var str_strange = '\u202A' + strange + amount;
```

`\u202A` is the unicode control character for LTR embedding. `\u202B` is for RTL embedding.

More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text#Table_of_possible_BiDi-types

You could also use the `\u200..` series. Just use `\u200E` for forcing it to LTR.

Snippet (with comnbinations):

```js
var strange = "د.إ", common = "$", amount = 50, strStrange = '';
strStrange = '\u202A' + strange + amount;
alert(strStrange);
strStrange = '\u200E' + strange + '\u200E' + amount;
alert(strStrange);
```